# Insert operation is not working for stl map in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, network-programming, client-server

In bellow c++ code i want to create one separate entry in stl map for each new connection from client.
there are two map one is map and another is map copy.Map conatin key as Final client ID(0-65535) and values (client port,client ip,server port,server ip,Initial client ID(0-255)).where as map copy contain key as above five tuple as key and Final client ID as value.
in run time for every connection it will check for client connection in mapcopy if it not exist in map copy then it will create new entry in both map.

Problem- For every connection it is giving the same Final client Id and it is 0 as output.I am not getting whether for every connection from client it is creating new map or it overriding previous value.

```
class Values
{
private:
    std::string client_addr;
    int client_port;
    std::string serv_addr;
    int serv_port;
    int Initial_client_ID;

public:
    Values(std::string,int,std::string,int,int);
    void printValues();

    /*comparator function for map insertion*/
    bool operator <( const Values &rhs ) const
    {
        return ( Initial_client_ID < rhs.Initial_client_ID );
    }
};

Values ::Values(std::string caddr,int cport,std::string saddr,int sport,int cid)
{
    client_addr=caddr;
    client_port=cport;
    serv_addr=saddr;
    serv_port=sport;
    Initial_client_ID=cid;
}

void Values::printValues()
{
    cout << client_addr<<":" <<client_port<<":" << serv_addr <<":" <<serv_port << ":"<<Initial_client_ID  <<endl;
}


//for map  and mapcopy insert and search operation

class Mapdetails:public Values
{
private:
    unsigned int Final_client_ID;
    map<int ,Values> items;
    map<Values,int> itemscopy;

public:
    Mapdetails(std::string f,int fp,std::string fgwa,int fgwp,int fd):Values(f,fp,fgwa,fgwp,fd) {}

    unsigned int MapResult(Values v1)
    {
        /*Check for the tuple entry exist in the second map*/
        map<Values,int>::const_iterator itemsIterator1 =itemscopy.find(v1);

        if(itemsIterator1==itemscopy.end())/*Entry for tuple does not exist*/
        {
            for(unsigned int key=0; key<=65535;    )
            {
                /*Find The available Key(Final clientID)*/
                map<int,Values>::const_iterator itemsIterator=items.find(key);

                if(itemsIterator==items.end())
                {
                    /*Insert into First map<int,Values>*/
                    items.insert(pair<int,Values>(key,v1));
                    {
                        /*Insert in to second map<Values.int>*/
                        map<Values,int>::const_iterator itemsIterator1;
                        itemscopy.insert(pair<Values,int> (v1, key));
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                /*If Key exist in to first map<int,Values>*/
                key=key+1;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        /*Entry exist in second map<Values,int>*/
        cout<<"Entry Already Exist"<<endl;
    }
    /*Search for the corresponding client entry in map<Values,int>*/
    itemsIterator1 =itemscopy.find(v1);
    if(itemsIterator1==itemscopy.end())
    {
        cout<<"Key not found";
    }
    else
    {
        /*Final client ID=Final_client_ID*/
        Final_client_ID=(*itemsIterator1).second;
        cout<<"Send data using key::::"<<Final_client_ID <<endl;
        return(Final_client_ID);
    }
}
};



//In main()


Values obj(inet_ntoa(Clientaddr.sin_addr),ntohs(Clientaddr.sin_port),inet_ntoa(Servaddr.sin_addr),ntohs(Servaddr.sin_port),starting_client_ID);

Mapdetails obj1(inet_ntoa(Clientaddr.sin_addr),ntohs(Clientaddr.sin_port),inet_ntoa(Servaddr.sin_addr),ntohs(Servaddr.sin_port),starting_client_ID);

Final_client_ID=obj1.MapResult(obj);
```

Comment: He's asking you to indent your so it is more readable.

Comment: @user3381955 And that did hinder you from indenting it properly? I doubt that. This is an unreadable mess, so please make it readable if you want people to help you.

Comment: I indented the code for you. Do you notice something wrong in there? ;) (Hint: Your MapResult member function is a complete mess.) Also you should really improve on your code's structure. You should be consistent when it comes to in and out of class definitions and you should comment on why you do something and not what you do.